# Splitting a single raster layer into multiple layers based on raster values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics

I am working with a raster layer in QGIS, and within this layer, the raster values are as follows: 10, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, and 30. I need the number of pixel of each value in city borders. I have a vector layer for cities.

Raster layer unique values report is useful but I need a city by city statistics like zonal statistics. I thought that by splitting each value as a different raster than I can use zonal statistics. Do you know an easier method for that? And do you know how can I split the pixels with specific band values as a different raster?

Comment: You are suggesting solution to your task instead of clearly describing task. See if something similar to arcgis 'tabulate area' tool exists in qgis. 99% chance it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to split your raster. [Zonal Histogram](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalhistogram) will create a column for each pixel value with the pixel count.

> Appends fields representing counts of each unique value from a raster
> layer contained within polygon features.

[image]